# QueryPerformanceFrequency weird behavior in one program, normal in other?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, time

I read Microsoft's documentation about `QueryPerformanceCounter()`, and wanted to make my own timer that counts time in seconds and milliseconds since the program started.

Everything was running fine on a test version of the program where I use 32-bit GCC.

But, after swtiching to "Main" (64-bit GCC), the program started to show "0" everywhere.
0 for milliseconds, 0 for seconds... all values were just 0 0 0 0 0...

I was searching where the problem is for a long time, and realized that maybe it is the Frequency, so I wrote a tiny line of code that makes sure the Frequency is not 0, and if it is then get the Frequency again.

```
if(qMSec==0){
    LARGE_INTEGER freq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    qFreq = (double)freq.QuadPart;
}
```

And it fixed it.

I know that many people follow the rule "if it works don't touch it", but I actually want to touch it and know why getting the Frequency fails. Microsoft said that since Windows 7+ this function doesn't fail anymore.

Here is the full class:

```
class qlTime{
public:
    
    LARGE_INTEGER qTime_Start,qTime_End;
    unsigned long int qSec,qMSec;
    double qFreq;
    
    qTimeClass(){
        qSec=0;
        qMSec=0;
        LARGE_INTEGER freq;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
        qFreq = (double)freq.QuadPart;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&qTime_Start);
    }
    
    void qReset(){
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&qTime_Start);
    }
    
    void Update(){
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&qTime_End);
        if(qMSec==0){
            LARGE_INTEGER freq;
            QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
            qFreq = (double)freq.QuadPart;
        }
        qMSec = ((qTime_End.QuadPart-qTime_Start.QuadPart)*1000.0)/qFreq;
        qSec  = ( qTime_End.QuadPart-qTime_Start.QuadPart)/qFreq;
    }
}qTime;
```

All I want is to understand why `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` sometimes works and sometimes does not?

And, is there a better solution than constantly checking if `qFreq` is set to 0 or not?

Comment: Check the return code, and if the function fails, check the error code returned by GetLastError.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes i did run and it's returning non zero value, also, just like i said and like Microsoft said, from WindowsXP this function should never fail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancefrequency

Comment: The code doesn't match your description. The class name is `qlTime` but the presumed constructor is called `qTimeClass`. The `Update()` method checks `qMSec` but your description says that you are constantly checking `qFreq`. my guess is that you are never actually calling `qTimeClass` to initialize `qFreq`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce except the interval is less than 1 microsecond or your usage is error @RaymondChen guessed. The function works fine as you said *it's returning nonzero value*. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank You, it's not the first time im completly blind, currently compiler is throwing so many warrnings that im not even reading them, trying to just make everything works and then I wanted to worry about warrnings, but Yes, it was indeed problem in that code that constructor had wrong name. I was so sure everything should work 100% fine that i didnt even checked if constructor is called. Thank You :)

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer and accept it. In general, if a program isn't working, you should investigate the compiler warnings before suspecting that the operating system is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very sorry for being blind and very thankful to Raymond Chen for pointing me that Constructor name was incorrect, Also I'm very sorry for blaming Microsoft when problem was on my side.

Thnak You all for help :)
//Edit:
@RaymondChen - I can't accept answer yet, it says i need to wait 19 hours to do it ( I will wait and accept it later then )